# エラー'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable の対処法

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Google ColabでPythonを実行してます。

```
list1 = [0]
if len[list1] == 1:
    print(“”)
```

このプログラムを実行しようとすると、

'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

というエラーが出ます。

stack overflowの英語版ではこのエラーの質問があったのですが、難しすぎて理解できませんでした。
日本語版ではこのエラーに関する質問が見当たらなかった(あまり上手い検索ができなかったのですが)ので質問させていただきました。

私は検索するときに、このエラー文をペーストしたのですが、もっと上手い検索の仕方があったら教えてください。

Comment: `len[list1]` ではなく、`len(list1)` です。

Comment: あ、確かに。ありがとうございます。

Comment: なお、`print(“”)` にも間違いがあるようです。 `“` と `”` は プログラミングで使われてりるダブルクォーテーションではありません。正しくは `"` です（開始も終了も同じくこの記号を使います）。

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージを単純に検索するのではなく、まずは、エラーの意味を理解しようとしてください。それだけで解決できる場合もありますし、わからなくて検索した場合でも、解決の手がかりが得やすくなります。

builtin_function_or_method は「組み込み関数またはメソッド」の意味です。[組み込み関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html)は初めから組み込まれた関数、組み込みメソッドは[組み込み型](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html)の初めから組み込まれたメソッドのことです。object はそのまま「オブジェクト」です。Pythonでは関数やメソッドもオブジェクトです。これが is not subscriptable、つまり、「subscriptできるものではない」となっています。subscrit は「添字する」の意味です。Pythonで「添字する」と言った場合、[添字表記](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions)のことを意味します。`なにか[なんたら]`というような表記のことです。

つまり、エラーメッセージは「組み込み関数またはメソッドであるオブジェクトは、添字表記することは出来ません。」という意味になります。

あとは、そのエラーメッセージが指摘する行を確認してください。そこには「組み込み関数」または「組み込みメソッド」があるはずです。そして、`組込関数またはメソッド[なんたら]`という形になっているはずです。関数やメソッドは添字表記することは出来ませんので、添字表記を止めて、あなたが本当にしたかった内容に修正してください。